# How to write aggregate query in LINQ reusing part of the select code

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have a reusable select query method called by two other methods.

These are the sample routines I have in my project. The SalesQry() method is actually very complex in our project.

```
Private IEnumerable<Sales> SalesQry(SalesDataContext sContext, int customerID)
{
   return 
      from SALE in sContext.Sales
      where SALE.CustomerID = customerID
      select SALE
}

Public List<SalesAGG> SalesByArea()
{
   SalesDataContext oSContext = new SalesDataContext (.....);

  return from SALE in SalesQry(sContext,1230)
              group SALE by
              new
              {
                Type = SALE.SaleType,
                Area = SALE.Area
              }   into aggAREA
             select new  SalesAGG()
             {
                Type = aggAREA.Key.Type,
                Place =  aggAREA.Key.Area,
                TotalSales = aggAREA.Count()
             }.ToList();     
}

Public List<SalesAGG> SalesByState()
{
   SalesDataContext oSContext = new SalesDataContext (.....);

  return from SALE in SalesQry(sContext,1230)
              group SALE by
              new
              {
                Type = SALE.SaleType,
                State = SALE.State
              }   into aggSTATE
             select new  SalesAGG()
             {
                Type = aggSTATE.Key.Type,
                Place =  aggSTATE.Key.State,
                TotalSales = aggSTATE.Count()
             }.ToList();            
}
```

The problem I am having is, when SalesByState() or SalesByArea() function is executed sql server is not running the aggregate query, instead it is just running this part returning large number of rows

```
from SALE in sContext.Sales
          where SALE.CustomerID = customerID
          select SALE
```

and remaining part is being executed inside the application. If I don't call the function SalesQry()
and changed the query like below, sql server ran an aggregate query returning very less number of rows.

```
 from SALE in sContext.Sales
 where SALE.CustomerID = 1230
 group SALE by
  new
  {
     Type = SALE.SaleType,
     State = SALE.State
   }   into aggSTATE
  select new  SalesAGG()
  {
    Type = aggSTATE.Key.Type,
    Place =  aggSTATE.Key.State,
   TotalSales = aggSTATE.Count()
  }.ToList();
```

I need to share the code because it is very complex and used in many other places. How should I write the query to make the sql server run the entire aggregate query on the server and also use the function SalesQry()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** It's probably that you're returning `IEnumerable<Sales>` instead of `IQueryable<Sales>`. I didn't catch that the first time.

I believe it's being forced to perform the aggregate on the client because it can't run `new SalesAGG()` on the database server. Try plucking it out with a `Let` statement, eg:

```
return from SALE in SalesQry(sContext,1230)
          group SALE by
          new
          {
            Type = SALE.SaleType,
            Area = SALE.Area
          }   into aggAREA
         let totalSales = aggAREA.Count()
         select new  SalesAGG()
         {
            Type = aggAREA.Key.Type,
            Place =  aggAREA.Key.Area,
            TotalSales = totalSales
         }.ToList();
```

If that isn't working, then my next hunch is that it's the `group by` clause that groups on a newed-up object. Try using string concatenation as the `group by` criteria instead, eg:

```
return from SALE in SalesQry(sContext,1230)
          group SALE by SALE.SaleType + SALE.Area into aggAREA
         select new  SalesAGG()
         {
            Type = aggAREA.First().Type,
            Place =  aggAREA.First().Area,
            TotalSales = aggAREA.Count()
         }.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Lawrence for your reply. I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. I also tried removing SalesAGG() and just made it "select new {Type = aggAREA.Key.Type, Place =  aggAREA.Key.Area, TotalSales = totalSales}.ToList()" using let totalSales = aggAREA.Count(). It is still returning all the data from the server.

Comment: See edit. It might work if the `group-by` is changed to a concatenated string value instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: No luck..It didn't work..The problem doesn't seem to be with groupBy, if I don't use the function SalesQry(sContext,1230), it is working correctly

Comment: Don't know why I missed this before, but it's because you're returning `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`.

Comment: Thanks a TONN Lawrence. That was it. It would take a day for me to find this bug without your help..